Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting web-1 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
I have made a Django project with a postgresql backend and am trying to containerize it.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - inventory_network

  db:
    ports: 
      - "5433:5432"
    image: postgres:16
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=InventoryManagement
    networks:
      - inventory_network

networks:
  inventory_network:
    driver: bridge

This is my settings.py within the django project to connect to the db:
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Inventory_management.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'InventoryManagement',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'db', 
        'PORT': '5433'
    }
}

The sudo docker build . command runs without any errors.
The error I get when I try to run 'sudo docker compose up' is as follows:
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting web-1 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
I have confirmed that the postgres server is running:
Server active(running)
This application also runs without any errors on my local.
I had created a network(inventory_network) on which I tried attaching my containers. But one thing I noticed was that whenever I ran the 'compose up' command, it created another network inventory_management_inventory_network automatically to which the containers attached instead of my specified network inventory_network:
This is what I got when i ran 'inspect' on both these networks, as I wasn't sure if this was related to the issue:
inventory_network inspect
inventory_management_inventory_network inspect
This is the complete error message:
sudo docker compose up
WARN[0000] /home/prisha/Inventory_Management/docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete                                                                                                                     
[+] Running 1/5
 ✔ Network inventory_management_default    Created                                                                                                                                                    0.3s 
 ⠋ Container rabbitmq-container            Created                                                                                                                                                    2.0s 
 ⠋ Container inventory_management-adminer  Created                                                                                                                                                    2.0s 
 ⠋ Container inventory_management-db-1     Created                                                                                                                                                    2.0s 
 ⠦ Container inventory_management-web-1    Created                                                                                                                                                    0.7s 
Attaching to inventory_management-adminer, db-1, web-1, rabbitmq-container
inventory_management-adminer  | [Tue Apr 16 17:16:29 2024] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://[::]:8080) started
db-1                          | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db-1                          | This user must also own the server process.
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db-1                          | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db-1                          | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | Data page checksums are disabled.
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db-1                          | creating subdirectories ... ok
db-1                          | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db-1                          | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db-1                          | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db-1                          | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db-1                          | creating configuration files ... ok
db-1                          | running bootstrap script ... ok
db-1                          | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db-1                          | syncing data to disk ... ok
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db-1                          | 
db-1                          |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db-1                          | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db-1                          | waiting for server to start....2024-04-16 17:16:48.579 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:48.585 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:48.631 UTC [52] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-16 17:16:34 UTC
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:48.648 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db-1                          |  done
db-1                          | server started
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.516 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db-1                          | waiting for server to shut down....2024-04-16 17:16:50.625 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.632 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.635 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.656 UTC [50] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.689 UTC [50] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.008 s, sync=0.011 s, total=0.055 s; sync files=2, longest=0.007 s, average=0.006 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB; lsn=0/14EAA70, redo lsn=0/14EAA70
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.696 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
db-1                          |  done
db-1                          | server stopped
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db-1                          | 
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.946 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.947 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.947 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:50.980 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:51.051 UTC [63] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-04-16 17:16:50 UTC
db-1                          | 2024-04-16 17:16:51.074 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web-1                         | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web-1                         | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
web-1                         | Traceback (most recent call last):
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web-1                         |     self.connect()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web-1                         |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
web-1                         |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web-1                         |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
web-1                         |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web-1                         |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web-1                         | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web-1                         |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web-1                         |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web-1                         | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web-1                         |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web-1                         |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web-1                         | 
web-1                         | 
web-1                         | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web-1                         | 
web-1                         | Traceback (most recent call last):
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
web-1                         |     self.run()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 917, in run
web-1                         |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
web-1                         |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
web-1                         |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
web-1                         |     raise _exception[1]
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
web-1                         |     autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
web-1                         |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
web-1                         |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
web-1                         |     app_config.import_models()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
web-1                         |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web-1                         |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web-1                         |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
web-1                         |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
web-1                         |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web-1                         |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
web-1                         |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
web-1                         |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
web-1                         |   File "/app/schema/models.py", line 17, in <module>
web-1                         |     Inventory.objects.create(**order_data)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
web-1                         |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
web-1                         |     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 739, in save
web-1                         |     self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 776, in save_base
web-1                         |     updated = self._save_table(
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 881, in _save_table
web-1                         |     results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 919, in _do_insert
web-1                         |     return manager._insert(
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
web-1                         |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
web-1                         |     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1414, in execute_sql
web-1                         |     with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web-1                         |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
web-1                         |     return self._cursor()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
web-1                         |     self.ensure_connection()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web-1                         |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web-1                         |     self.connect()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web-1                         |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
web-1                         |     self.connect()
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web-1                         |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
web-1                         |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
web-1                         |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
web-1                         |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web-1                         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web-1                         |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web-1                         | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web-1                         |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web-1                         |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web-1                         | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web-1                         |         Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web-1                         |         TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web-1                         | 
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.701302+00:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application syslog exited with reason: stopped
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.720113+00:00 [notice] <0.248.0> Logging: switching to configured handler(s); following messages may not be visible in this log output
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.721332+00:00 [notice] <0.248.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.778579+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> ra: starting system quorum_queues
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.778737+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> starting Ra system: quorum_queues in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4777f5259953/quorum/rabbit@4777f5259953
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.896967+00:00 [info] <0.262.0> ra system 'quorum_queues' running pre init for 0 registered servers
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.945305+00:00 [info] <0.263.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system quorum_queues. 0 record(s) recovered
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.957634+00:00 [notice] <0.268.0> WAL: ra_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_log_closed_mem_tables
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.968432+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> ra: starting system coordination
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.968511+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> starting Ra system: coordination in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4777f5259953/coordination/rabbit@4777f5259953
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.969487+00:00 [info] <0.275.0> ra system 'coordination' running pre init for 0 registered servers
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.970048+00:00 [info] <0.276.0> ra: meta data store initialised for system coordination. 0 record(s) recovered
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.970225+00:00 [notice] <0.281.0> WAL: ra_coordination_log_wal init, open tbls: ra_coordination_log_open_mem_tables, closed tbls: ra_coordination_log_closed_mem_tables
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.977368+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> ra: starting system coordination
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:56.977434+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> starting Ra system: coordination in directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@4777f5259953/coordination/rabbit@4777f5259953
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.172023+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> Waiting for Khepri leader for 30000 ms, 9 retries left
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.225862+00:00 [notice] <0.284.0> RabbitMQ metadata store: candidate -> leader in term: 1 machine version: 0
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.247313+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> Khepri leader elected
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.868397+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> 
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.868397+00:00 [info] <0.248.0>  Starting RabbitMQ 3.13.1 on Erlang 26.2.2 [jit]
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.868397+00:00 [info] <0.248.0>  Copyright (c) 2007-2024 Broadcom Inc and/or its subsidiaries
rabbitmq-container            | 2024-04-16 17:16:57.868397+00:00 [info] <0.248.0>  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
rabbitmq-container            | 
rabbitmq-container            |   ##  ##      RabbitMQ 3.13.1
rabbitmq-container            |   ##  ##
rabbitmq-container            |   ##########  Copyright (c) 2007-2024 Broadcom Inc and/or its subsidiaries
rabbitmq-container            |   ######  ##
rabbitmq-container            |   ##########  Licensed under the MPL 2.0. Website: https://rabbitmq.com
rabbitmq-container            | 
rabbitmq-container            |   Erlang:      26.2.2 [jit]
rabbitmq-container            |   TLS Library: OpenSSL - OpenSSL 3.1.5 30 Jan 2024
rabbitmq-container            |   Release series support status: supported
rabbitmq-container            | 
rabbitmq-container            |   Doc guides:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/documentation
rabbitmq-container            |   Support:     https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/contact
rabbitmq-container            |   Tutorials:   https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials
rabbitmq-container            |   Monitoring:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/monitoring
rabbitmq-container            | 
rabbitmq-container            |   Logs: <stdout>
rabbitmq-container            | 
rabbitmq-container            |   Config file(s): /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf
rabbitmq-container            |                   /etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/20-management_agent.disable_metrics_collector.conf
rabbitmq-container            | 
rabbitmq-container            |   Starting broker...2024-04-16 17:16:57.869626+00:00 [info] <0.248.0> 

I have tried everything I know and would really appreciate any inputs.

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. [edit] the question and include code fragments with the code sample button ({}).

Sure, I've added that now!

Are you sure you don't have any other DATABASES variable in your settings? From your error it seems like it's looking for the database on localhost and not what you've configured in the settings that you show.

Also why are you checking whether the database is running on your machine directly when you've configured the app to use the one setup using docker compose?

Once you get it to be used, also note the DATABASES setting is wrong: connections between containers always use the standard port for the target container and ignore ports: if they're present, so you need the standard PostgreSQL port 5432 here.

I am pretty sure there shouldn't be a conflicting DATABASES variable. Most of it was the default django project code, I just changed the database connection parameters.

@DavidMaze I rebuilt it with the port 5432 and this is what I got:
'web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/init.py", line 122, in connect
web-1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web-1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web-1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web-1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web-1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address'

As @AbdulAzizBarkat's comment above suggests, it looks like your application isn't seeing that DATABASES configuration.

So what do you suggest I do about this? I also do not understand why a different network inventory_management_inventory_network automatically gets created to which the containers attached instead of my specified network inventory_network, which comes up empty upon inspection

It'd be helpful to know what your project layout looks like. Is it something like this?
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── Inventory_management
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt

Can you please add this information to your question?
Also, for the setup you describe you should be using port 5432 (not 5433) in your settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "InventoryManagement",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "root",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": "5432",
    }
}

As noted in one of the comments, port mappings don't apply to connections between containers.

Yes my project layout is exactly like that. I have changed the port to 5432, but it didn't make a difference to the error message.

Weird. Could you please add the context of the error message to your original question? What I'd like to see is the complete error message along with the stack trace so that I can see where that error is being generated.

Yeah sure! I have added the complete error message in my original question. Hopefully the stack trace gives some idea.

can you change 5432:5432
for connections in docker
and
in settings engine "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",

@SujaySBadge I tried that, doesn't make a difference. I think the main issue lies in the changes of django settings.py not being reflected. Not sure how to fix that though.

In the error log, there is a line as "WARN[0000] /home/prisha/Inventory_Management/docker-compose.yml: version is obsolete":

docker-compose.yml: version is obsolete"

As Docker has made this version line obsolete, remove this line from the docker-compose.yml file which is most probably causing this problem.
